# How better store info about categories in a database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, database-design, ef-code-first

Which approach is better in designing database in Entity Framework Code First. To add category in an entity as a string or as an object. What are actually consequences in futher developing?

I wonder there appear problems in case I decide for solution A with editable SelectLists.

solution A:

```
class Advertisement : BaseObject
{
    int AdvertisementId { get; set; }
    string User { gest; set; }
    string Title { get; set; }
    string Content { get; set; }
    decimal Price { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Region { get; set; }
    bool Featured { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    IEnumerable<File> Photo { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType=email)]
    string Email { get; set; }
    string Phone { get; set; } 
    string Address { get; set; }
}
```

solution B:

```
class Advertisement : BaseObject
{
    int AdvertisementId { get; set; }
    string User { gest; set; }
    string Title { get; set; }
    string Content { get; set; }
    decimal Price { get; set; }
    public virtual City City { get; set; }
    public virtual Region Region { get; set; }
    bool Featured { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    IEnumerable<File> Photo { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType=email)]
    string Email { get; set; }
    string Phone { get; set; } 
    string Address { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What do you think makes sense for your use case?

Comment: I have my own thoughts, but I ask about best practices and consequences of these two approaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution A would make sense in two use case:

- The available categories are hard coded but in this case enum would
  be a better choice
- The Category entity is present in a different context and you wan't
  to decouple the two context by not referencing another entity. In
  this case however you should use the unique identifier of the
  category.

Soultion B should be used in any other case as it would

- make easier to access a category entity through a proxy object
  generated by the Entity Framework
- it would make possible to use any other property of the category
  instead of its name which might become necessary later in relevant
  thus this approach provides more flexibility
- in the generated database it would only use the identifier of the
  category to connect the Advertisement and Category tables